# How to format EGLD value send to SC/Account?

Tags: multiversx, erdpy

I'm trying to send an EGLD value (e.g. 1.5 EGLD) to an account/smart contract but in some cases only BigUInt type seems to be allowed.
How does this value work and how should I format it correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the MultiversX blockchain, each token is configured to have a specific number of decimals (between 0 and 18).
EGLD is configured to have 18 decimals. So, `1` EGLD is actually the denominated representation of the integer value of `10^18` actually.

Using this example, if you have to send `1.5` EGLD, the un-denominated integer value is `1.5 * 10^18 = 1500000000000000000`.

If you send the tx from mxpy or most of any other programmatic way, you should pass the un-denominated value.
If you send the tx from web wallet and such user-friendly interfaces, there's a good chance that the values are already denominated automatically, so `1.5` EGLD will be automatically denominated to the actual `1.5 * 10^18` value, which is what the destination address/SC will receive as payment amount.